# IntelliJ Spring Boot test always hangs

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have an IntelliJ gradle project created from VCS. Every so often the git root becomes read-only and git operations will fail until I go to the file system and enable full control. This was livable with, but a new different problem has emerged also that also relates to this -
When I try to run my spring boot integration test it keeps hanging at "Instantiating tests" with nothing written on the console. Then once I force-stop it, then trying to run the integration test or any unit test will fail with

> Could not set process working directory to
> 'C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\projectname': could not set current
> directory (errno 5)

None of the suggestions on the internet for this problem viz delete your `.idea` folder, invalidate the cache and restart IntelliJ, etc worked. Some answers also suggest checking the Working directory in the Run configuration but for the life of me, I find no such textbox at all in my run configuration. However when I go to the file system I find that the project root directory has the read-only attribute set at this point in time, and once I re-enable full control, then I will be able to run the unit tests, but if I attempt to run the integration test it would just hang like I mentioned, and then the whole cycle starts all over again.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the working directory in the configuration, as said in the thread in https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207043685-Problem-with-Error-Cannot-start-process-the-working-directory-does-not-exist- ?

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't see any working directory at all in the Run configuration.

Comment: The "Working Directory" field is in the Run Configuration of your Spring Boot test. Something like `Shift + Alt + F9` → Select your test → press Right → select "Edit..."

Comment: Is it possible to move project to some other location? Are access rights changed when IDE is not used?